# docusign api create new account

Tags: php, docusignapi

i have created a master account manually on docusign and now i want to create new users using this account. This is my code:

```
$integratorKey = 'XXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX';
$email = 'my-email';
$password = 'XXXX';
$name = 'User';

$header = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" . $email . "</Username><Password>" . $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";



$data = '{
  "newUsers":[{
    "activationAccessCode":"",
    "email":"my-email@gmail.com",
    "enableConnectForUser":"",
    "firstName":"",
    "forgottenPasswordInfo":{
      "forgottenPasswordAnswer1":"",
      "forgottenPasswordAnswer2":"",
      "forgottenPasswordAnswer3":"",
      "forgottenPasswordAnswer4":"",
      "forgottenPasswordQuestion1":"",
      "forgottenPasswordQuestion2":"",
      "forgottenPasswordQuestion3":"",
      "forgottenPasswordQuestion4":""
    },
    "groupList":{
      "groupId":"",
      "groupId":""
    },
    "lastName":"",
    "middleName":"",
    "password":"",
    "sendActivationOnInvalidLogin":"",
    "suffixName":"",
    "title":"",
    "userName":"username",
    "userSettings":[{
      "name":"",
      "value":""
    }]
  }]
}';  




$requestBody = "\r\n"
."\r\n"
."--myboundary\r\n"
."Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
."Content-Disposition: form-data\r\n"
."\r\n"
."$data\r\n"
."--myboundary--\r\n"
."\r\n";

$url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts";


$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestBody);                                                                  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($requestBody),
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )                                                                       
);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ( $status != 201 ) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status . "\nerror text is --> ";
    print_r($json_response); echo "\n";
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);

var_dump($response);
```

The error that i am getting is this : { "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_BODY", "message": "The request body is missing or improperly formatted. Input string was not in a correct format." }. Could anyone tell me what is the issue?

Comment: Use `json_encode` on an array of data instead of trying to construct the JSON as a string manually.

Comment: it doesnt seem to be the issue with the json syntax cos when i use json_decode i am getting an array ..i am using the example from this link : http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Add%20User%20to%20Account.htm.

Comment: Looking at their example it sounds like `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` should be `$data` not `$requestBody` try that.

Comment: i got it. it was a problem with the json format. i removed all the unwanted values and it worked..thanks

Comment: can you please post an answer here and mark the question as resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Developer had an issue with the json format. There were unwanted values that got removed and it's now working (Based on comments above). Making sure this is marked as answered.